# Rails Bootstrap 3 with Webpacker - Dropdown not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpacker

I know I can use bootstrap since containers/rows are working on this website but for some reason it doesn't look like the JS is working for Bootstrap.

I have the following setup in app>assets>javascripts>application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require rails-validator
```

Within app>javascript>packs>application.js

```
import "babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js";
import nav from "./nav";
```

app>javascript>packs>styles>bootstrap.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables';
```

config>webpack>environment.js

```
const environment = require('./environment')
environment.plugins.get("UglifyJs").options.uglifyOptions.ecma = 5
module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Gemfile.lock

```
bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
  autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
  sass (>= 3.3.4)
```

I've no idea what I need to update to get the JS to actually work.

I've tried updating the app>javascript>application.js with:

```
// JS libraries
import "jquery"
import "jquery-ujs"
import "bootstrap"
```

This results in Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "jquery-ujs" and Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined.

I tried adding to app>javascript>application.js with:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
Rails.start();
```

Then in my config>webpacker>environment.js with:

```
const {
  environment
} = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

End up with bootstrap.js:7 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "popper.js" and home.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Comment: You might find this useful: https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding the popper gem in your project. If I remember it is not included automatically.
https://github.com/glebm/popper_js-rubygem

Comment: Tried that. Added //= require popper to application.js within app>javascript>application.js after adding in the gem and running bundle install. No errors but nothing happens.